# ADF task modification

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf, azure-pipelines-tasks

```
@string(equals(substring(pipeline().globalParameters.ENVIRONMENT_ROOT_FOLDER,0,2)),(substring(pipeline().parameters.TargetPath),1,3)))
```

*this throws error :: function 'equals' does not accept 1 argument(s)*

- basically this code wants to check what is current environment and if
  the target path contains the current environment , this will go to
  false.
- For example if i am running this ADF pipeline from DEV and target
  path contains a path with a location from dev ( say  dev\xyz\kty) it
  will fail /go to false. else it will be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
@equals(tolower(pipeline().globalParameters.ENVIRONMENT),'prod')
```

this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I have tried to use the similar dynamic content as yours with my parameters.

[image]

- The error is because there is an additional `)` before specifying the second argument inside equals function and therefore while parsing the expression, this extra parenthesis is being considered as end of equals function. So, removing it gives the desired result (Even the second substring has some errors, I have changed it as required).

```
@string(equals(substring(pipeline().parameters.root_folder,0,2),substring(pipeline().parameters.target_path,1,3)))
```

[image]

- Replace the `root_folder` and `target_path` parameters with your required values.

Comment: i am afraid this did not work however i have found the way which i mentioned in my answer. let me know if that works for you too. thanks .

Comment: Add the values of the global parameter in the question and that should give more clarity.